# INSERT or UPDATE is uniqu value exists

Tags: mysql

Here is my current statement

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, DOB, ACCESSION, EXAM_DESC, LOCATION, EXAM_DATE, REFERRING)
VALUES (${patientIdentification_patientName_familyName},${patientIdentification_patientName_givenName},${patientIdentification_dateOrTimeOfBirth_value},${commonOrder_placerOrderNumber_entityIdentifier},${observationRequest_relevantClinicalInfo_value},${patientVisit_assignedPatientLocation_facility},${observationRequest_observationDateOrTime_value},${observationRequest_orderingProvider_familyName})
```

ACCESSION is unique in the db. What I need to do is if the ACCESSION value already exists then I want to replace the row. If it does not exist (the value of ACCESSION is unique) I want it to INSERT.

Comment: (The name of that question may seem different, but the underlying question is the same: "How can I perform an insert-or-update in MySQL?")

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your variables that you are using php to do this. Correct me if i am wrong.
This is how you would check if it exists:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DBTable WHERE ACCESSION = '$ACCESSION'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row > 0)
{
    //code for when the record exists (update)
}
else
{
    //code for when the record does not exist (insert)
}
```

Follow this and modify it for your dbtable and values etc.
This should do what u want it to do

Comment: I am using Mirth so if I use anything other than a mysql statement it needs to be javascript. Can you should how this would be done with JS?

Comment: I am not familiar with javascript, i am jearning that language myself. I know php and learning it in java but not that far yet. But i know the principles and method will be the same but the language will be diffrent.